# I need To All Data In $qryy It Return Only Last Record

Tags: codeigniter

How I Return all data of `$qryy` it's return me only last record. How I need return all off data.

```php
public function get_subcategory(){
    $qry = $this->db->get("shopping_category");
    foreach($qry->result() as $row){
       $this->db->where("c_id",$row->id);
       $qryy = $this->db->get("shopping_subcategory");
    }
    return $qryy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use another approach to resolve your problem: use joins to query the database only once:

```
$this->db->join("shopping_subcategory t2","t2.c_id=t1.id");
$qry = $this->db->get("shopping_category t1");
return $qry->result();
```

if you output above with `print_r($qry->result())`, you get similar to below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [company_ID] => 1
            [name] => aaa
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [company_ID] => 1
            [name] => bbb
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [company_ID] => 2
            [name] => ccc
        )
)
```

to resolve your approach: you need to make $qryy an array, to store each subquery data, right now you are overwriting the variable $qryy with each loop and therefore only get the last result:

```
$qry = $this->db->get("shopping_category");
$qryy=array();
foreach($qry->result() as $i=>$row){
   $this->db->where("c_id",$row->id);
   $qryy[$i] = $this->db->get("shopping_subcategory")->result();
}
return $qryy;
```

if you output above with `print_r($qryy)`, you get similar to below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [company_ID] => 1
                    [name] => aaa
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [company_ID] => 1
                    [name] => bbb
                )    
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 4
                    [company_ID] => 2
                    [name] => ccc
                )
        )
)
```

therefore, depending which approach you use, you'll need to take care of your data output differently.

helpful info on joins [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: I've edited my answer, I missed to return a result in the foreach loop, sorry. I've added generated output examples: using join, it returns an array of objects, while "your" approach returns a nested array with arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
public function get_subcategory() {
        $result = [];
        $qry = $this->db->get("shopping_category");
        foreach ($qry->result() as $row) {
            $this->db->where("c_id", $row->id);
            $qryy = $this->db->get("shopping_subcategory");
            $result[] = $qryy;
        }
        return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the last record is,  every time you loop data through foreach it keeps replacing `$qryy = $this->db->get("shopping_subcategory");`

to fix this you can simply change `$qryy` into an array `$qryy[]` like this.

To improve your query. you can simply try

```
$qryy = [];
$this->db->select("shopping_subcategory.*");
$this->db->from("shopping_category");
$this->db->join('shopping_subcategory', 'shopping_category.id = shopping_subcategory.c_id');
$sql= $this->db->get();
$qryy  = $sql->result_array(); 


$data['category'] = $qryy;
$this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```

In view

`$category` will show your data

Comment: error :: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::reset_array()

Comment: @RhtGhodadra code changed please check. I missed 1 line

Comment: check  again `$sql= $this->db->get();
 $qryy  = $sql->result_array(); ` 2 lined added

Comment: Call to a member function result() on null

Comment: oops sorry. how i get data in to view.

Comment: @RhtGhodadra check now

Comment: foreach($subcategory as $sub_cat) {  echo $sub_cat->sub_cat_name; 
                           } error:: TRYING TO GET PROPERTY "CATEGORY_NAME" OF NON-OBJECT

Comment: @RhtGhodadra your question is about the issue in query and you are asking a new question in the comment. Please post as new if it's not duplicated

Answer (score 0):

I think it solve your problem. would you mind if you give it a try?

since you want from table `shopping_category` is only `id` i try to fetch it so it's not a heavy duty on your server.

```
        $result = [];
        $qry = $this->db->select("id")->get('shopping_category');
        foreach ($qry->result() as $row) {
            $this->db->where("c_id", $row->id);
            $qryy = $this->db->get("shopping_subcategory")->result();
            $result[] = $qryy;
        }
        return $result;
```

Hope that helps :)